# Lazy loading not making a call to the function

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

When I was debugging my application I found that the code line below is not making a call to any method in my service layer:

```
private Lazy<List<userAudit>> lazyList = null;
lazyList = new Lazy<List<userAudit>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());
```

And, my `GetAudit` method will return the list of Audit Object and below is its definition:

```
public List<t_user_audit> GetAudit(int id)
{
   return _work.GetGenericRepositoryFor<List<userAudit>>().GetByID(id);
}
```

And, in the above definition, I have inserted a break point, in the `GetAudit` method, but when the compiler is not coming to the break point and just returning me with the `NULL` values.

I don't know where I have made a mistake or is what wrong with the code.

I am following [Can you explain Lazy Loading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading) article.

Comment: Does it work when you skip `Lazy` and set field to `List<userAudit>` directly?

Comment: Have caled `lazyList.Value` ? I think you didn't.

Comment: i haven't check that, but i was in the middle to implement the `Lazy Loading`, so skipped it.

Comment: The action would be invoked on `lazyList.Value`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan where i have to call `lazyList.Value`, do i have to equate `lazyList.Value = new Lazy<List<userAudit>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());`, or you mean something else.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i been following this example, please go through it :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the `Lazy` class is, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Provides support for lazy initialization.`

So it's normal that

```
lazyList = new Lazy<List<userAudit>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());
```

doesn't call this method.

However, it will be called if you use the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

Comment: sorry, dnt get you, because i am new to the technology, can you please explain a bit more, what i have to do now to get the values... and make a call to the function...

Comment: +1. @HarshSharma have you tried to call `var v = lazyList.Value` as suggested in comments?

Comment: No, i dnt tried that, but yeah this is the solution, and its working, thanks guys for your help, keep the great work up like that..

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading means get value at the time you need or use it

Here

```
lazyList = new Lazy<List<userAudit>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());
```

You are only creating predicate or you can say signature for you query means method wont get called
as soon as you use it like mention below

```
var output = lazyList.Value;
```

method get called

Comment: thanks man for your help, i was unaware of the fact that i have to call the `.Value` to initialize the object, but nice answer thanks